# Laravel relations, same parent as grandparent: good practice or not?

Tags: php, database, laravel, database-design, eloquent

Since you can define relationships really easy with the Laravel framework. I wonder if it is good practive to have a `nation_id` in the `athletes` table.

[image: nations as parent and grantparent of athletes]

I set up the following relationships within Laravel:

---

**Nation model:**

```
public function athletes() {
    return $this->hasMany(Athlete::class, 'id', 'nation_id');
}
```

**Club model:**

```
public function nation() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Nation::class, 'nation_id', 'id');
}
public function athletes() {
    return $this->hasMany(Athlete::class, 'id', 'club_id');
}
```

**Athlete model:**

```
public function nation() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Nation::class, 'nation_id', 'id');
}
public function club() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Club::class, 'club_id', 'id');
}
```

Since you can do this to get the nation of an athlete: `Athlete::where('id', $id)->first()->club->nation`, I wonder if it is good practice to have a nation function in there as well.

Comment: You can append it as a property and simple call Athlete::find($id)->nation, but i think that club nation and Athlete nation are not necessary the same. Then calling Athlete::find($id)->club->nation returns the Club nation.

Comment: But I wonder if this has more server load or is unnecessarily. Are there disadvantages?

Comment: Not really. I think it's fine if an athlete can only have one nation and you don't need more information about (for example when the user nation changed). Don't think in performance here, but think about how it will work for you.

Comment: Thank you Jefferson, really helpful. I was unsure about my approach, but thanks. The nation of the user itself can't change, but the club of the user can, and so the club-nation of the user. In this case, I think a `hasManyThrough` won't be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `hasManyThrough` on the `Nation` model to access `Athlete` without having to have a direct relation between the two.

So on your **Nation** model:

```
public function clubs()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Club::class);
}

public function athletes()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Athlete::class, Club::class);
}
```

Comment: can you do this with more than a total of 3 models?

Comment: You cannot use `hasManyThrough` with more than 3 but you can start eager loading on the `hasManyThrough` after 3 like `Nation::with('athletes.events')->get()`